# Access apps with AppleScript

Tags: ios, applescript, itunes

Is there anyway to programmatically get a list of iOS apps from iTunes?

AppleScript does not seem able to do this.

The only way I can think of is looking in the 'iTunes Media/Mobile Applications' folder. But this way a lose all metadata.

Any suggestions to get list of iOS apps including the metadata?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now actually went with the solution to scan the 'Mobile Applications' folder.

In order to get the metadata I had to do the following:

- the *.ipa are simply archives
- unzip/extract the 'iTunesMetadata.plist' inside
- parse the plist
- voila you got all metadata

This whole process is actually pretty straightforward in python as your already have both zipfile and plistlib.

One thing to lookout for though is that plistlib in python can not handle the new binary plist files. So you first have to convert them to their corresponding xml format. (only some *.ipa seem to be in binary form).

This can be done quite easily with the following line of code:

```
os.system("/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 %s" % file_name )
```

Now the only thing I still have to figure out is how to get the currently installed apps on the device...